# A statistic representative of time series data

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics

I am working on a project that requires me to analyse a couple of indices over a period of time, around 5 years. My scenario is as follows

I have a feature (% of people who has access to water) country wise. There are 5 percentages for different years (2014-2019)
e.g:

> A - 78%, 80%, 81%, 85%, 88% - increasing trend
>
> B - 78%, 85%, 80%, 81%, 88% - increasing, decreasing, increasing trend

Now I need one figure that represents these 5 numbers, something like an average. I know average will not work here, case the average of both the instances A, B would be the same. I need a number that gives something like the mean, variance of the distribution and an indicator of the trend (+/-)

Please let me know what I should be looking into, or if I have missed something here

TIA 
=)

Answer (score 0):

You might cluster your time series in five dimensional space, to see how many types you have. Done that, a good summary might be the centroid of the cluster each series belongs to, possibly suplemented by the distance to such centroid. K-means clustering seems appropriate here.